# How to override class from package as a ObservableObject?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have few classes in package and depending on implementation i wish to make it useful in fe. iPhone app. Is there anyway to something like override package class with ObservableObject?

Package

```
class Team{
var name = "" 
}
```

App

```
override Team: ObservableObject // or sth like that

@EnvironmentObject team1: Team
```

Comment: You can create a sub class or wrap Team in another class (or make Team conform to ObservableObject directly)

Comment: What you are looking for is an `extension`, that's how you can make existing types conform to protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your package class(es) into one new class, that publishes all of them for the UI:

```
class Team {
    var name: String = "Test"
    
}

class PublishedPackages: ObservableObject {
    @Published var team = Team()
    // ... other package classes
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var publishedPackages = PublishedPackages()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(publishedPackages.team.name)
                .padding()
            
            Button("change") {
                publishedPackages.objectWillChange.send()
                publishedPackages.team.name = "other Name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```