# SwiftUI MVVM With ObservedObject

Tags: class, mvvm, swiftui, observedobject

**UPDATE (2/10/22 @ 11:30am CST):**

I rewrote the workflow so that my viewModel conforms to the ObservableObject protocol and no longer conforms to the CreateUser class. Now my variables are updating properly (tested via `print("\(viewModel.loadingStatus)")` both before and after the loadingState value is set.

However, my view that uses a switch statement to show the current state of the view (i.e. switches on loadingState) does not update, even though the value of loadingState in the viewModel is being set correctly and I'm able to use that print statement to show that it's being set, in the view itself.

I even tried setting changing the viewModel's @Published var loadingState to read as:

```
@Published var loadingState: LoadingState = .loading {
    willSet {
        objectwillchange.send()
    }
}
```

Of course, according to Apple's docs, that's exactly the same behavior as @Published by itself, and it did nothing to solve the issue.

It seems as though everything else is working properly, except for the view switch case not updating when loadingState changes in the viewModel.

---

**Original Post:**

I have a multi-page form where all of the views of the form share the same ObservableObject(s). What I would like to do is split up each individual view into an MVVM workflow so that the UI stuff is in the view and the data stuff is in the viewModel.

The issue is that since all of these views share the same ObservableObject(s), and the functions in each of the views make heavy use of these ObservableObjects (storing variables, using other functions, etc.), the viewModel can't just be an ObservableObject of its own, because I would need to write a custom intializer for everything (and there are a lot of variables). This also means that in my NavigationLink as well as the view's preview, I would have to call to every single one of those individually initialized vars.

CreateUser (the shared ObservableObject that has all of the form variables as @Published vars) is where I am setting all of the form variables as the user moves through the pages. The best I came up with was to conform my viewModel to CreateUser instead of simply ObservableObject. That seemed to work and after quite a bit of recoding, there were no more errors and my app built. That being said, as it's not working, I have a feeling that this is not the correct way to do it.

Unfortunately, it seems that the viewModel is not updating any of the CreateUser variables, nor is it accurately referencing the CreateUser variables that are being set. I tested this by using page 3 of the form (where the username is entered) as the test for the MVVM architecture, and asked it to print the variable from page 2. It returned the default value instead of what was actually set.

This means my data is not being passed through properly and my variables are not being referenced the way they should, so page 3 (the MVVM view) is stuck showing the loading state, even though it should show the loaded state once the json fetch is finished.

What is the proper procedure for instituting an MVVM workflow when you have multiple other ObservedObjects being utilized in each view? This is for the latest SwiftUI/XCode for iOS 15+.

Here's a bit of code to further explain (obviously very stripped down for this post, but you get the idea if you read my explanation above):

Main View:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct UsernameView: View {

@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                switch viewModel.loadingState {
                    case .loading:
                        Section {
                            Text("I am loading")
                        }

                    case .loaded:
                        Section {
                            Text("I am loaded")
                        }

                    case .failed:
                        Section {
                            Text("Something went wrong")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            viewModel.userActivity = Date.now
            jsonFetch.sink (receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                    case .failure:
                        viewModel.loadingState = .failed
                    case .finished:
                        viewModel.loadingState = .loaded
                    }
                },
                receiveValue: { loadedData in
                    viewModel.userData = loadedData
                }).store(in: &viewModel.dataTransfer.requests)
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

extension UsernameView {
    class ViewModel: CreateUser {

        @ObservedObject var textBindingManager = TextBindingManager(limit: 15)
        
        @Published var loadingState: LoadingState = .loading
        @Published var userData: [Usernames] = []
        @Published var usernameExists: [UsernameExists] = []

        func editingChanged(_ value: String) {
            username = String(value.prefix(textBindingManager.characterLimit))
            
            let jsonFetchUserExistsURL = URL(string: "https://api.foo.com/userselect?user=\(user)")
            let jsonFetchUserExistsTask = dataTransfer.jsonFetch(jsonFetchUserExistsURL, defaultValue: [UsernameExists]())
            
            if username.count >= 8 {
                guard network.isNetworkActive else { loadingAlert = true; return }
                Task {
                    status = .loading
                    usernameExists.removeAll()
                    jsonFetchUserExistsTask.sink (receiveCompletion: { completion in
                        switch completion {
                        case .failure:
                            self.loadingState = .failed
                        case .finished:
                            return
                        }
                    },
                    receiveValue: { loadedUserExists in
                        self.usernameExists = loadedUserExists
                    }).store(in: &dataTransfer.requests)
                }
            }
        }

extension UsernameView.ViewModel {
    enum LoadingState {
        case loading, loaded, failed
    }
}
```

CreateUser:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class CreateUser: ObservableObject {
    
    @ObservedObject var dataTransfer = NetworkTransfer()
    let network: NetworkMonitor
    
    init(network: NetworkMonitor) {
        self.network = network
    }
    
    @Published var userActivity = Date.now
    @Published var userActivityAlert = false
    @Published var birthday = Date()
    @Published var username = ""
}
```

Comment: At least for me, there's really not enough to tell what's going on here. It's not compilable, since there are a bunch of missing types, and it's not really clear what the intent is from reading the code, since I can't tell what's an issue because it isn't included and what's an issue because it's broken. Is it possible to include a [mre]?

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048505/how-to-override-class-from-package-as-a-observableobject/71048864#71048864

Comment: jnpdx: The only reason it doesn't compile is because I didn't include my jsonFetch function in the sample code. Otherwise the example code is fine. I also included quite a lengthy explanation. All the pages of the multi-page form utilize the CreateUser class in order for it to hold all the variables as the user registers. Then you have one of the views of the multi-page form. That view is what I am trying to split up into an MVVM workflow, but since it uses the CreateUser class variables in the functions I'm getting stuck.

Comment: ChrisR: I looked at that link and your post, but I don't think that's the answer because all I want to do is split up the view, not make the entire thing a packaged class. I further explained things in my comment above to jnpdx.

Comment: I could just make the viewModel it's own ObservableObject, but the issue is that there are so many variables I have to manually initialize, the NavigationLink that points to this view from the previous page of the form (not too mention the preview of the view itself) becomes ridiculous.

Comment: I edited the text of this post to explain things more clearly. Hoping that helps.

Comment: Added an update to the main post

Comment: You could update your code fixing the thing mentioned in the other answer where they identified your use of StateObject and ObservedObject is backwards. And you can’t have @ObservedObject in a class either.

Comment: @kittonian (FYI, if you don't precede a user's name with an `@`, they don't get a notification when you respond). There's more missing code besides `jsonFetch`. Also, `TextBindingManager`, `Usernames`, `UsernameExists`, `NetworkTransfer`, `NetworkMonitor`. I did read the description, but I was still (personally) a little lost. That's why I thought maybe some runnable code would help understand the situation.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use MVVM in SwiftUI, SwiftUI is automatically managing the views layer like UILabels on screen etc. for us, we work with the view data in `View` structs, hence no need for extra view model objects. We also don't use `sink` in our `ObservableObject`s we instead `assign` to `@Published` which completes the pipleline and ties its life-cycle to the object (no need for cancellables).

Since you are using async/await in a task you don't even need Combine's `ObservableObject` anymore and can simply use the `.task` modifier and set the result on a `@State`.

Take a look at [task(id:priority:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(id:priority:_:)) and you'll notice it can re-run the task when ever the id param changes and cancelling previous tasks. It's now as simple as setting result of your await to an `@State` which can either be the data array or a custom struct containing the data and other related vars.

We do however use an `ObservableObject` reference type to manage the life cycle of our value-type model data, i.e. to persist or sync it.

Comment: Lots of people split up their views into an MVVM workflow. In fact, many of the SwiftUI teachers have courses teaching MVVM for SwiftUI.

Comment: I know, it is extremely frustrating!!! They should all go watch WWDC videos before they write courses.

Comment: @malhal I think the concept of going without a VM in SwiftUI is an interesting one. The concept definitely makes sense in a relatively simple project, but I have to admit, as a project grows, I find it challenging to wrap my head around some of it. I saw one of the WWDC videos that you linked to and have it on my list to rewatch. Two brief questions: 1) Are you familiar with TCA? I think it's debatable whether or not some of their concepts could be considered view models. Do you have an opinion on that architecture? 2) Is there actually any guidance from Apple directing people away from MVVM?

Comment: I took your advice and forgot about trying to do the whole MVVM thing. I actually got pretty close but nesting ObservableObjects does not work too well. Instead I am taking your advice and breaking it all up into separate view and structs/classes.

Comment: @jnpdx 1) yes and I would advise against it because centralising navigation breaks SwiftUI's simple design of using modifiers like onOpenURL for handling deep links or onContinueUserActivity for state restoration all way down the View hierarchy. It's like they designed it before they fully understood all the ways to do things in SwiftUI. 2) MVVM is a pattern designed for UIKit, you won't see it mentioned in any of the SwiftUI data flow talks by experts Curt, Luca or Raj.

Comment: @kittonian great. Yes don't attempt to nest ObservableObject. Create one ObservableObject to hold your model value types in @ Published properties. Using bindings like $model.property in your Views.

Comment: @jnpdx A key difference is in MVVM the view model object stores manually localised strings, whereas in SwiftUI we pass string and a formatter to Text and if the region settings change, SwiftUI will automatically update UILabels on screen with newly formatted localised strings. There is a lot of magic going on in the View struct and it is actually behaving like an object. If we stored manually localised strings in a view model object in SwiftUI then we'd lose this magic behaviour and the UI would be buggy like UIKit UIs usually are because none of this is handled.

Comment: In my efforts to break everything up, I got to page 3 (the username view) and sure enough, the loadingState did not work, even though it works fine on page 1 and is now in a separate observable class. I got it to work by manually setting the variable (loadingState.loadingState = .loading) before my jsonFetch task runs when the view appears. This leads me to believe that my MVVM was working the same way and was just fine. I am using LoadingState() to create a new one on page 1 but if I do the same on page 3 it hangs. Do I need to kill the first one somehow before instantiating a new one?

Comment: @malhal Interesting. I (personally) wouldn't frame the localization of strings as a key difference. I'd say (again, personally), separating networking logic away from the view would be more of a key difference, for instance. And, I'm not necessarily convinced that SwiftUI actively discourages that sort of use of what many call a "view model". I wish Stack Overflow were more well suited to this type of discussion, because I think it would be interesting to explore this more with you, but at this point, I think I'm hijacking the comments thread...

Comment: @jnpdx "separating networking logic away from the view" remember the View data struct is not the view in the MVC or MVVM sense. SwiftUI uses the View data structs, diffing them, and generates the UILabels, UITableViews etc. actual views for us. It's perfectly fine to do networking in the View data struct and the new task modifier is designed for exactly that!

Comment: @malhal — seems like that would make testing more challenging.

Comment: @jnpdx I haven't tried it myself but it looks really easy to test async await in Xcode 13 with XCTest

Comment: @malhal oh, that's definitely true. But, one of the benefits of separating the view logic from other traditional business logic has been that you can have your UI and logic tests separate (and, for example, mock network calls and effects). If everything is wound up in the view, this seems a little more challenging.

Comment: @jnpdx Apple recommend putting logic into custom structs to make that testable, see 4:18 in Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020. Also with async/await the async functions usually are already in different structs. Someone who wants to do async testing will need to put some effort in and learn the new XCTest features though.

Comment: @malhal I understand the conceptual difference between the `View` data struct and what is rendered on the page. What I am not necessarily convinced of is the idea that SwiftUI is diametrically opposed to ever separating out this type of logic from the `View` (with a capital `V`) object. I think it's a choice, but I don't necessarily think it's always the right or wrong choice. Interesting discussion, though.

Comment: I rewrote my comment above

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be important to take a look at your `NavigationLink`s and way you are passing down the view model to the multiple pages of the form from a parent view. I don't see how this is done in your post, however, so my answer will be a guess.

My assumption is that `UsernameView` is one of the multiple pages of your form, and all of the pages in your form all use `@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel`. This would be a red flag, if you want to share the same view model across all of them. `@StateObject` signifies that the view *owns* that object, and will hold onto it  for the lifetime of the view. `@ObservedObject` on the other hand is a *reference* to an `ObservableObject` that should be passed into the view. If the multiple pages of your form all use `@StateObject`, then it's possible that the way you've constructed things, you're getting distinct instantiations of your view model, which is why you're seeing default values in other pages for a previous page's input.

Here is a simple, high-level overview of how I might go about it.

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var page = 1
    var body: some View {
        switch page {
        case 1:
            ChildView1(viewModel: self.viewModel)
        case 2:
            ChildView2(viewModel: self.viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ChildView1: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.username)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ChildView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.username)
    }
}
```

The example would show the same username in both child views. The parent did a single instantiation of the view model via the `@StateObject`, and passed it down to the children without re-instantiating the model into the `@ObservedObject`s. This way, you will have the same object in memory correctly shared among the views.

Comment: Thank you for trying but your assumptions are incorrect. I only have a single @StateObject var in my UsernameView because that is pointing to the UsernameViewModel that specifically pertains to the MVVM structure/workflow of the Username page of the form.

Comment: Added an update to the main post

Answer (score 0):

I ended up forgetting about trying to use an MVVM workflow. Unfortunately, though I recoded everything and got it pretty close to working, the nested ObservedObjects do not update the view. After quite a bit of research I found several articles stating the same.

Instead, I decided to follow malhal's suggestion of breaking everything up into separate views, structs, and classes. It's a serious pain the ass, but hopefully it'll make the code a bit easier to work with as things progress.

I appreciate everyone's input.